# Wso2 password reset with email confirmation code invalidates after one use

Tags: wso2, forgot-password, change-password

WSO2 has a 6 step process for updating a password through email.

```
getCaptcha() -­ Generates a captcha.
verifyUser() -­ Validates the captcha answer and username and returns a new key.
sendRecoveryNotification() -­ Send an email notification with a confirmation code to the user. Need to provide the key from previous call.
getCaptcha() ­- Generates a captcha when the user clicks on the URL.
verifyConfirmationCode() -­ Validates the captcha answer and confirmation code. This returns a key.
updatePassword() -­ Updates the password in the system. Need to provide the key from previous call, new password and returns the status of the update, true or false.
```

Step 3 sends a confirmation code to an email address to then be provided in step 5, verifying that the user is correct.

The problem occurs when a person enters a password that they had already used. If the password entered was used in the past, the database will reject that password, thus having WSO2 return a password update error. When a person then goes to enter a new password, the confirmation code has been invalidated. This means that a user has to start the entire process over again to get a new code to reset their password.

Is there a setting to prevent the confirmation code from invalidating itself if an incorrect password is input?

Their website states:

Also for each communication, the generated confirmation code is not reused by the service. This makes the services secure and fails repeated attempts to access the same service. Hence the sequence of calls which the Calling Application must do is as follows for email-based recovery:

Does this mean that one user in a password update session only has one try to change their password?

Comment: Where does this password validation happens? Is it underlying ldap\AD which WSO2 Identity Server plugged in to?

Comment: Yes. The underlying LDAP will take the password passed in by wso2 and if the password has already been used in the LDAP, it will not accept it. Then WSO2 will return an error for updating the password. If the password fails to update, the confirmation code has already been used, and cannot be used again. This means the user will have to get a new email to step through the process again.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a limitation in current version 5.0.0.

Created a JIRA [1] to mentioning this requirement.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3175

HTH,
DarRay